# Ask for user authentication with iOS app in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

Is there any way to prompt for the Touch ID authentication when app is running in background when a push notification arrives?

Thanks,
Puneet

Comment: Never heard of such a thing. Seeing as iOS9 supports iphone 5 and 4s which don't even have touch ID authentication. I don't think this is possible. It might be POSSIBLE if you can somehow manipulate iOS settings but no one but people working at Apple would know how to do this. Would most likely be rejected from the app store if someone did take this route to implement it. Would basically be considered a hack. Authentication is authentication whether its fingerprint or passcode.

Comment: If the user taps the push notification to launch your app, then you can prompt for TouchID when your app enters the foreground but if they don't tap the notification then you can't do anything

Comment: After launching the app its trivial enough, just wanted to know if its possible without that. Thanks! :)